# Why does "include" behave differently in the global context than it does in a class?

Tags: ruby

In the global context (main), when you include a module you can use its methods directly from the global context. In a class, including the module defines instance methods which can't be called from the same context that include was called from. Why is this?

Example:

```
module Foo
  def hello
    puts "Hello, world!"
  end
end

# In a class:
class Bar
  include Foo
  hello # Hello is an instance method so it won't work here.
end

# In main
include Foo
hello # Works fine. Why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In main
>
> include Foo
>
> hello # Works fine. Why?

[***What is the Ruby Top-Level?***](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/) a good blog on this concept you must go thorugh first.

Because in top level you are calling the instance method `#hello` on the top level object `main`,which is an instance of `Object` class.On top level you are doing `include Foo` means you are including the module in the `Object` class.which is why instance method `#hello` of the module `Foo` becomes the instance method of the class `object`.

```
module Foo
  def hello
    puts "Hello, world!"
  end
end
Object.include?(Foo) # => false
include Foo
Object.include?(Foo) # => true
self # => main
self.class # => Object
self.instance_of? Object # => true
hello # => Hello, world!
```

On top level if you are calling the method as `hello`,but ruby is doing internally as `self.hello`. And `self` is there `main`,which I explained before.

Comment: "Because in top level you are calling the instance method `#hello` on the top level object `main`,which is an instance of `Object` class."

Hold on. If `main` is an instance of the `Object` class, than how come `include` works on the top level when `Object.new.send(:instance_eval) do include Foo; end` doesn't? (It throws a `NoMethodError` for `include`.)

Comment: My point is, `include` isn't defined on `Object`: `Object.new.respond_to? :include #=> false`. So why is it defined on `main`?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Please go thorugh [What is the Ruby Top-Level?](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/)

Comment: @Ajedi32 can you come here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38656/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-brabertaser1992

Comment: Okay so `main` is not *just* an instance of `Object`, it has all this other special behavior as well. That answers my question, thanks.

Comment: @Ajedi32 on top level the role of `self` is getting switched to either class `Object` or instance of Object,i.e. `main` , as per the need.Like when you did `include M`,the role of `self` was `Object` class,and when you call the method `#hello`,then the role of self is `main`.